# SQL Server recursive query issue

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have an issue with a query against one of our MS SQL Server databases.  The following tables and views are simplified for the sake of brevity but should serve to describe the problem.

Each table's score is compiled as the average of its immediate children.  The views suffice for the fixed structures but it gets more complex with the location hierarchy which is currently in nested set form.  There is no fixed number of tiers in the location hierarchy as they are user defined.

I tried solving this using a recursive CTE but they do not allow for aggregation in the recursive part.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[locations_main](
    [id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [lft] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [rgt] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [parent_id] [smallint] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_locations_main] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[locations_main] VALUES
    (1, 'location 1', 1, 16, NULL),
    (2, 'location 1-1', 2, 9, 1),
    (3, 'location 1-1-1', 3, 4, 2),
    (4, 'location 1-1-2', 5, 6, 2),
    (5, 'location 1-1-3', 7, 8, 2),
    (7, 'location 1-2', 10, 15, 1),
    (8, 'location 1-2-1', 11, 12, 7),
    (9, 'location 1-2-2', 13, 14, 7)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[outcomes](
    [id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [location_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_outcomes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[outcomes] VALUES
    (1, 3, 'outcome 1'),
    (2, 4, 'outcome 2'),
    (3, 5, 'outcome 3'),
    (4, 8, 'outcome 4'),
    (5, 9, 'outcome 5')
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[prompts](
    [id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [outcome_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_prompts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[prompts] VALUES
    (1, 1, 'prompt 1'),
    (2, 2, 'prompt 2'),
    (3, 3, 'prompt 3'),
    (4, 4, 'prompt 4'),
    (5, 5, 'prompt 5')
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[subprompts](
    [id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [prompt_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [score] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_subprompts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[subprompts] VALUES
    (1, 1, 'subprompt 1', 1),
    (2, 1, 'subprompt 2', 1),
    (3, 2, 'subprompt 3', 1),
    (4, 2, 'subprompt 4', 3),
    (5, 3, 'subprompt 5', 2),
    (6, 3, 'subprompt 6', 4),
    (7, 4, 'subprompt 7', 1),
    (8, 4, 'subprompt 8', 5),
    (9, 5, 'subprompt 9', 3),
    (10, 5, 'subprompt 10', 3)
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_prompts]
AS
SELECT
    dbo.prompts.id,
    dbo.prompts.outcome_id,
    dbo.prompts.name,
    AVG(dbo.subprompts.score) AS score
FROM dbo.prompts
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.subprompts
    ON dbo.prompts.id = dbo.subprompts.prompt_id
GROUP BY
    dbo.prompts.id,
    dbo.prompts.outcome_id,
    dbo.prompts.name
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_outcomes]
AS
SELECT
    dbo.outcomes.id,
    dbo.outcomes.location_id,
    dbo.outcomes.name,
    AVG(dbo.vw_prompts.score) AS score
FROM dbo.outcomes
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vw_prompts
    ON dbo.outcomes.id = dbo.vw_prompts.id
GROUP BY
    dbo.outcomes.id,
    dbo.outcomes.location_id,
    dbo.outcomes.name
GO
```

The query below retrieves all the locations but it calculates the averages from the leaf nodes not the immediate children of the location in question -

```
SELECT loc_main_ag.name, AVG(CAST(vw_outcomes.score AS FLOAT))
FROM locations_main loc_main_ag
LEFT JOIN locations_main loc_main
    ON loc_main_ag.lft <= loc_main.lft
    AND loc_main_ag.rgt >= loc_main.rgt
INNER JOIN vw_outcomes
    ON loc_main.id = vw_outcomes.location_id
GROUP BY loc_main_ag.name
```

returns

```
location 1       2.4
location 1-1     2
location 1-1-1   1
location 1-1-2   2
location 1-1-3   3
location 1-2     3
location 1-2-1   3
location 1-2-2   3
```

"location 1" has the average of "location 1-1-1", "location 1-1-2", "location 1-1-3", "location 1-2-1" and "location 1-2-2" - (1+2+3+3+3)/5 = 2.4 instead of the average of "location 1-1" and "location 1-2" - (2+3)/2 = 2.5

I tried to tackle this by using a CTE but hit a problem with using GROUP BY and aggregate functions within the recursive part of the CTE -

```
WITH location_scores
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
-- Get score for all leaf node locations
SELECT locations_main.id, locations_main.name, locations_main.parent_id, AVG(CAST(vw_outcomes.score AS FLOAT)) AS score
FROM locations_main
INNER JOIN vw_outcomes
    ON locations_main.id = vw_outcomes.location_id
WHERE locations_main.rgt - locations_main.lft = 1
GROUP BY locations_main.id, locations_main.name, locations_main.parent_id

UNION ALL

-- Recursive member definition
-- Rollup through locations parents to build averages
SELECT locations_main.id, locations_main.name, locations_main.parent_id, AVG(CAST(location_scores.score AS FLOAT)) AS score
FROM locations_main
INNER JOIN vw_outcomes
    ON locations_main.id = vw_outcomes.location_id
INNER JOIN location_scores
    ON locations_main.id = location_scores.parent_id
GROUP BY locations_main.id, locations_main.name, locations_main.parent_id

)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT *
FROM location_scores
```

**UPDATE**: Here is my attempt at a table valued function.  It returns the correct results based on the simplified example included here but I am concerned about how this will scale.  The hierarchy it will be executed against in the wild can have somewhere in the region of 15^5 records.

```
CREATE FUNCTION scores () RETURNS
    @result TABLE
    (
        id              SMALLINT,
        name            NVARCHAR(50),
        lft             SMALLINT,
        rgt             SMALLINT,
        parent_id       SMALLINT,
        score           FLOAT,
        [level]         SMALLINT
    ) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @level INT
    SET @level = 1

    INSERT INTO @result
        SELECT
            locations_main.id,
            locations_main.name,
            locations_main.lft,
            locations_main.rgt,
            locations_main.parent_id,
            AVG(CAST(vw_outcomes.score AS FLOAT)) AS score,
            @level AS [level]
        FROM locations_main
        INNER JOIN vw_outcomes 
            ON locations_main.id = vw_outcomes.location_id 
        WHERE locations_main.rgt - locations_main.lft = 1 
        GROUP BY
            locations_main.id,
            locations_main.name,
            locations_main.lft,
            locations_main.rgt,
            locations_main.parent_id

    WHILE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @result WHERE level = @level AND parent_id IS NOT NULL ) > 0 BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @result
        SELECT
            locations_main.id,
            locations_main.name,
            locations_main.lft,
            locations_main.rgt,
            locations_main.parent_id,
            AVG(CAST(res.score AS FLOAT)) AS score,
            (@level + 1) AS [level]
        FROM locations_main
        INNER JOIN @result res
            ON locations_main.id = res.parent_id
            AND res.level = @level
        GROUP BY
            locations_main.id,
            locations_main.name,
            locations_main.lft,
            locations_main.rgt,
            locations_main.parent_id

        SET @level = @level + 1

    END

RETURN
END
```

I would really appreciate some comments as to whether this is a suitable approach or not.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear because it isn't obvious what your data looks like and what results you expect. Can you post a simple test case that shows exactly what you're trying to achieve? The test case doesn't have to use your real tables or data, it just has to illustrate your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the table valued function that I have come up with.  I don't suppose it will be useful to anyone due to the nature of the problem but I am including it here the the sake of completeness.  With a combined total of 920k records across the entire hierarchy this returns in 3 seconds on our dev server.

```
CREATE FUNCTION cqc_location_template_scores (@location_id INT = NULL) RETURNS
    @result TABLE
    (
        id              SMALLINT,
        name            NVARCHAR(50),
        lft             SMALLINT,
        rgt             SMALLINT,
        parent_id       SMALLINT,
        score           FLOAT,
        [level]         SMALLINT
    ) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @level INT
    SET @level = 1

    DECLARE @lft INT, @rgt INT
    IF (@location_id IS NOT NULL)
        SELECT @lft = lft, @rgt = rgt FROM locations_main WHERE id = @location_id
    ELSE
        SELECT @lft = NULL, @rgt = NULL

    DECLARE @ROLLUP_TYPE VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT @ROLLUP_TYPE = parmvalue FROM globals WHERE parameter = 'CQC_ROLLUP_TYPE'

    -- TEST TO GUARD AGAINST INFINITE LOOP CAUSED BY LOCATIONS_MAIN RECORD BEING ITS OWN PARENT
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM locations_main WHERE id = parent_id) > 0)
        RETURN


    INSERT INTO @result
        SELECT
            locations_main.id,
            locations_main.name,
            locations_main.lft,
            locations_main.rgt,
            locations_main.parent_id,

            CASE @ROLLUP_TYPE
                WHEN 'AVE' THEN CAST(ROUND(AVG(CAST(CODE_CQC_STATUS.cod_score AS FLOAT)), 0) AS INT) 
                WHEN 'WORST' THEN MIN(CODE_CQC_STATUS.cod_score)
                ELSE NULL
            END AS score,

            @level AS [level]
        FROM locations_main
        INNER JOIN cqc_outcomes 
            ON locations_main.id = cqc_outcomes.cdo_location
        INNER JOIN CODE_CQC_STATUS
            ON cqc_outcomes.cdo_status = CODE_CQC_STATUS.CODE
        WHERE locations_main.rgt - locations_main.lft = 1
        AND (locations_main.lft >= @lft OR @lft IS NULL)
        AND (locations_main.rgt <= @rgt OR @rgt IS NULL)
        GROUP BY
            locations_main.id,
            locations_main.name,
            locations_main.lft,
            locations_main.rgt,
            locations_main.parent_id

    WHILE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @result WHERE level = @level AND parent_id IS NOT NULL ) > 0 BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @result
        SELECT
            locations_main.id,
            locations_main.name,
            locations_main.lft,
            locations_main.rgt,
            locations_main.parent_id,

            CASE @ROLLUP_TYPE
                WHEN 'AVE' THEN CAST(ROUND(AVG(CAST(res.score AS FLOAT)), 0) AS INT) 
                WHEN 'WORST' THEN MIN(res.score)
                ELSE NULL
            END AS score,

            (@level + 1) AS [level]
        FROM locations_main
        INNER JOIN @result res
            ON locations_main.id = res.parent_id
            AND res.level = @level
        WHERE (locations_main.lft >= @lft OR @lft IS NULL)
        AND (locations_main.rgt <= @rgt OR @rgt IS NULL)
        GROUP BY
            locations_main.id,
            locations_main.name,
            locations_main.lft,
            locations_main.rgt,
            locations_main.parent_id

        SET @level = @level + 1

        -- TEST TO GUARD AGAINST INFINITE LOOP
        IF (@level > 10)
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM @result
            RETURN
        END

    END

RETURN
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I could not format the sql code when I copy it on my SSMS

But what I can say about recursive queries in SQL Server is that they are formed of two parts. One anchor and one recursive part.

You can check the article http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-recursive-query-with-recursive-cte.aspx for recursive samples

And if Group By is causing a problem, you can think a way of grouping the query result outside the recursive part.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  I do not think the CTE option is viable due to the inability to use GROUP BY in the recursive part.  Without the GROUP BY, using recursion in this query serves no purpose as the hierarchy can be returned directly using the nested set related query.  I am hoping someone can suggest a different approach which will server my needs.